# Forms are not working after putting htaccess code to remove php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am setting up htaccess file to remove php extensions form pages. The code of htaccess is working fine and removing the extensions but forms are not working. If I remove htaccess file, forms start working.

Here is my htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What exactly does "_forms are not working_" mean? They don't show up? Submit wrong values? Look weird? What have you tried already to fix the problem?

Comment: forms does not submit values.

Comment: Can you share the form start tag?

Comment: Have you checked inside file by `die("here i am...")` in the starting of file to check is it the correct file you are looking and after htaccess it is going inside that file or not...?

Comment: here is the form code:

Comment: <form action="login.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="text" name="password">
 <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
echo $username = $_POST['username'];
echo $password = $_POST['password'];
}